# Radzen Blazor DataGrid Filter not working

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, radzen

Using the Radzen DataGrid and attempting to set filters. The basic filters work but have not had success the advanced or simple with menu. The issue is when filtering on a column that contains a template column or a date, it provides no results. Otherwise only the regular text fields work for the filtering both numeric and alpha. This can be seen in their demo at [Radzen DataGrid Simple Filter with Menu](https://blazor.radzen.com/datagrid-simple-filter-menu). Click in the employee column filter box, enter a name that is in the list then press enter. No results are found. Same result when using the date picker on the date field. I realize that the image in the template field may suggest the problem but I copied the code from the demo and removed the image altogether and just had the text field within the template and that did not work. For the [Radzen DataGrid Advanced Filtering](https://blazor.radzen.com/datagrid-advanced-filter), their demo I had to copy the code and implement the template column. This did not work for filtering either. Also in their demo the date filter is not the date picker like it is in the simple with menu demo. Entering the date as text does not return any results either.

I also looked at possibly using MudBlazor DataGrid but that is not completed yet and the documentation does not show much for filtering anyway. I am open to trying other components but don't want to waste to much time searching for one that will work if there is a way to get this one to work.

As a note, I did post a message on their community board. Unfortunately, the received response was unhelpful and showed disinterest in fixing the bug.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @emix The question is, is there a way to apply the filter to a column in a Radzen DataGrid that contains a template or a datetype field that works? If not, is there an alternate Blazor component that is free that has a data grid which functions correctly? Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by adding `Type` parameter.

```
<RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Employee" Type="typeof(DateTime)" Title="DateOfBirth" Property="DOB">                    
    <Template Context="columnContext">
        <DateTimeColumnTemplate columnContext="columnContext" Property="DOB"></DateTimeColumnTemplate>
    </Template>   
</RadzenDataGridColumn>
```

Comment: I am not in the office today but will give that a try after the weekend. However I did previously try the Type without the typeof() and was receiving NullReferenceExceptions on the DataGrid. Hopefully the typeof() will resolve that error and make it function properly. Also as a note the filtering for the template field did not work for any data type not just date and separately filtering did not work on a regular datetime column without a template context. Hoping this will fix it for both situations. Thanks again,

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to get back has some EF issues causing the build to fail. I copied the code above and VS said it could not find the DateTimeColumnTemplate. I searched for that and did not find any component for Radzen that has that name. I also tried the TType="typeof(DateTime)" and that did not work in a standard column without a template. With the template for plain text fields I found sometimes it seems to work but have trouble with after the first filter typing more than 1 character gets the next character deletes and have to type it a second time. Copy paste fails also.

Comment: `<DateTimeColumnTemplate>` is just an example. you have to create your own template that match with your requirement.